# Having issue start up opensearch stack(docker-compose file)

Tags: elastic-stack, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

I am trying to stand up a opensearch cluster by using the example from the opensearch webstite
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/install/docker/

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.2.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"]' # must be a string with no spaces when specified as an environment variable
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

But opensearch dashboard fail to start up with the following error message. If i check the log from the one of open search node, i got “failed to resolve host”, can anyone point to me what went wrong ?

Open search dashboard error:

```
[2021-12-30T00:28:19,773][WARN ][o.o.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [opensearch-node1] failed to resolve host [opensearch-node2]

java.net.UnknownHostException: opensearch-node2

at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[?:?]

at org.opensearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:605) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:547) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:999) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:177) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]

at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:733) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
```

Open search node error:

```
[2021-12-30T00:28:19,773][WARN ][o.o.d.SeedHostsResolver  ] [opensearch-node1] failed to resolve host [opensearch-node2]

java.net.UnknownHostException: opensearch-node2

at java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:800) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366) ~[?:?]

at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300) ~[?:?]

at org.opensearch.transport.TcpTransport.parse(TcpTransport.java:605) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.transport.TcpTransport.addressesFromString(TcpTransport.java:547) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.transport.TransportService.addressesFromString(TransportService.java:999) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at org.opensearch.discovery.SeedHostsResolver.lambda$resolveHostsLists$0(SeedHostsResolver.java:177) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]

at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:733) ~[opensearch-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue on the mac.
But it gets resolved when I increase the memory size in docker-desktop

Comment: I've increased to 30GB and still have the same problem. Do you have any solutions?